# Unable to find Player Assembly Unity Android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I have the following warning in the Unity console when I try to build my project into my Meta Quest 2:

> D:[path_to_unity_project]\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.TestRunner.dll

It does not prevent me from building the project, however I cannot use the build: inside the headset I have a little window, with which I cannot interact. It seems that Unity fails to build the player.

I have already tried (as explained in another thread) to add a `link.xml` file with this lines:

```xml
<linker>
     <assembly fullname="UnityEngine.TestRunner" preserve="all" />
</linker>
```

However, this attempt was not successful.

Moreover, I have tried also to delete the `Library` folder, to check if Unity, re-creating it, could solve this issue, but without any results.

Can someone help me?